# Issue with Stripe Checkout and Stimulus Controller in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I'm encountering issues with rendering the Stripe Checkout and connecting a Stimulus controller in my Rails application. I've outlined the details below:

- The Stripe Checkout component is not rendering.
- The client-side logs and console logs related to Stripe are not
  displaying any information.

Stimulus Controller:

- The Stimulus controller is not connecting properly.
- console.log statements within the Stimulus controller are not outputting anything.

Relevant Code:

stripe_controller.js

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static values = { publicKey: String, clientSecret: String }
  stripe = Stripe(this.publicKeyValue, { betas: ["embedded_checkout_beta_1"] });

  connect() {
    console.log("Stimulus controller connected");
  }

  async connect() {
    console.log("Connect method is called");
    console.log("Public Key:", this.publicKeyValue);
    console.log("Client Secret:", this.clientSecretValue);

    this.checkout = await this.stripe.initEmbeddedCheckout({
      clientSecret: this.clientSecretValue
    });

    console.log("Checkout Object:", this.checkout);

    this.checkout.mount(this.element);
  }

  disconnect() {
    this.checkout.destroy();
  }
}
```

importmap.rb

```
# Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap

pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
```

show.html.erb

```
<h1>Checkout Page</h1>
<%# <script type="module" src="/javascript/controllers/stripe_controller.js"></script> %>
<div data-controller="stripe"
  data-stripe-public-key-value="<%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:stripe, :publishable_key)%>"
  data-stripe-client-secret-value="<%= @session.client_secret %>">
</div>
```

Steps Taken:

I've checked the import map configuration and ensured correct paths.
Assets have been precompiled after modifying the import map.
The javascript_importmap_tags are placed in the head of my layout file.

---

UPDATE

In the application.js file I console.logged and this did not log anything.

---

Errors Encountered:

In the browser console, I'm seeing errors like:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "application". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@hotwired/turbo-rails". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Versions:

Rails version: Rails 7.0.8
Turbo version: @hotwired/turbo-rails: 8.0.0-beta.2

The application runs on localhost.
I've tried changing Stripe keys to test keys, but the issue persists.

Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing these issues and how to resolve them would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think the issue is related to Stripe. Something is wrong with the dependency management.

Comment: Why do you pin @hotwired/turbo-rails to application.js? Try to change this line to ... to: "turbo.min.js" (and include the rubo-rails gem). At least in my Application I can use Turbo with Stripe. And another observation: Perhaps the beta-Version of Turbo 8 is not ready for production yet :)

Comment: @zaphodbln_ Thank you for you response, I changed it back to turbo.min.js as I tried application to see if i could get it to work this way,. I added a console.log to the application.js file which didn't work therefore I think there is a problem with my asset pipeline maybe ? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing the javascript include tag for application in the head of my application.html.erb, as the <%= javascript_importmap_tags %> handles everything. Then added this line:
import { StripeController } from "./stripe_controller"; to my application.js file like so:

app/javascript/controllers/application.js

```
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus";
import { StripeController } from "./stripe_controller";

const application = Application.start();
application.register("stripe", StripeController);
application.debug = false;
window.Stimulus = application;

export { application };
```

and in the stripe controller i changed from this:

```
export class extends Controller {
```

to this:

```
export class StripeController extends Controller {
```

I also had imports that weren't pinned in my importmap, I have commented them out too like so:

app/javascript/application.js

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
// import "bootstrap"
// import "jquery"
// import "popper.js"
```